# Undefined al imprimir variable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Tengo el siguiente código donde en las funciones `addPregunta`, `addResouesta`y `addCotizacion` trato de imprimir `this.graphDefinition` e imprime indefinido. No sé cuál es la verdadera razón para tener esto porque cuando trato de imprimir la misma variable pero sin Angular/Ionic3 y usando las mismas variables funciona.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import {
  IonicPage,
  NavController,
  NavParams,
  AlertController
} from "ionic-angular";
import * as mermaid from "mermaid";
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as shortid from "short-id";
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: "page-flow-chart",
  templateUrl: "flow-chart.html"
})
export class FlowChartPage {
  agregar = document.getElementsByClassName("agregar");
  respuesta = document.getElementsByClassName("respuesta");
  cotizacion = document.getElementsByClassName("cotizacion");
  pregunta = document.getElementsByClassName("pregunta");
  @ViewChild("mermaid")
  public mermaidDiv;
  propiedades: string;
  clases: string;
  uniones: string;
  graphDefinition: string;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {
    this.propiedades = `
    P0:::inicial
    P1:::pregunta
    P2:::pregunta
    P3:::pregunta
    R1:::respuesta
    R2:::respuesta
    R3:::respuesta
    R4:::respuesta
    R5:::respuesta
    R6:::respuesta
    R7:::respuesta
    R8:::respuesta
    R9:::respuesta
    C1:::cotizacion
    C2:::cotizacion
    C3:::cotizacion
    A1:::agregar
    A2:::agregar
    A3:::agregar
    `;
    this.clases = `
    classDef inicial fill: #F1F1F1, stroke: #3590C4, stroke-width: 4px, color: #3590C4, font-weight: bold, font-size: 10px
    classDef pregunta fill: #F1F1F1, stroke: #F1F1F1, stroke-width: 4px, color: #3590C4, font-weight: bold, font-size: 10px
    classDef respuesta fill: #F1F1F1, stroke: #F1F1F1, stroke-width: 0px, color: #243E56, font-weight: bold, font-size: 10px
    classDef respuesta:hover fill: #288AC1, stroke: #288AC1, stroke-width: 0px, color: #FFFFFF, font-weight: bold, font-size: 10px, cursor: pointer
    classDef cotizacion fill: #F2680A, stroke: #F2680A, stroke-width: 4px, color: #FFFFFF, font-weight: bold, font-size: 10px
    classDef cotizacion:hover fill: #F2420A, stroke: #F2420A, stroke-width: 4px, color: #FFFFFF, font-weight: bold, font-size: 10px, cursor: pointer
    classDef agregar fill: #F1F1F1, stroke: #243E56, stroke-width: 1px, color: #243E56, font-weight: bold, font-size: 10px, stroke-dasharray: 5
    classDef agregar:hover fill: #D3D3D3, cursor: pointer
    `;
    this.uniones = `
    P0(Pregunta) --> R1(Respuesta 1)
    P0(Pregunta) --> R2(Respuesta 2)
    P0(Pregunta) --> R3(Respuesta 3)
    R1 --> P1(Pregunta 1)
    R2 --> P2(Pregunta 2)
    R3 --> P3(Pregunta 3)
    P1 --> R4(Respuesta)
    P1 --> R5(Respuesta)
    P2 --> R6(Respuesta)
    P2 --> R7(Respuesta)
    P3 --> R8(Respuesta)
    P3 --> R9(Respuesta)
    R6 --> C1(Precio)
    R7 --> C2(Precio)
    R8 --> C3(Precio)
    R4 --> A1(+ Agregar)
    R5 --> A2(+ Agregar)
    R9 --> A3(+ Agregar)
    `;
    this.graphDefinition = `
    graph TD
    ${this.propiedades}
    ${this.uniones}
    ${this.clases}
    `;
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.mermaidStart();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.agregar.length; i++) {
      this.agregar[i].addEventListener("click", this.addElement, false);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.respuesta.length; i++) {
      this.respuesta[i].addEventListener("click", this.addRespuesta, false);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cotizacion.length; i++) {
      this.cotizacion[i].addEventListener("click", this.addCotizacion, false);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.pregunta.length; i++) {
      this.pregunta[i].addEventListener("click", this.addCotizacion, false);
    }
  }
  mermaidStart() {
    mermaid.initialize({
      theme: "default",
      securityLevel: "loose",
      startOnLoad: true,
      flowchart: {
        useMaxWidth: true,
        htmlLabels: true
      }
    });
    const element: any = this.mermaidDiv.nativeElement;
    mermaid.render("graphDiv", this.graphDefinition, svgCode => {
      element.innerHTML = svgCode;
    });
  }
  addPregunta() {
    console.log(this.graphDefinition);
    alert("Pregunta");
  }
  addRespuesta() {
    console.log(this.graphDefinition);
    alert("Respuesta");
  }
  addCotizacion() {
    console.log(this.graphDefinition);
    alert("Cotizacion");
  }
  addElement() {
    this.uniones += "R9 --> A2";
    alert("Funciona la ejecucion");
  }
}
```

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>flowChart</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div class="graph">
    <div #mermaid></div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: una pregunta te funciona la primera vez pero al intentarlo nuevamente te dá el error??. Recuerda no es muy recomendable seguir usando JQuery con angular, lo que haces con JQuery lo puedes hacer directamente con angular

Comment: Si jquery esta inportado de mas disculpa. La cuestion es que cuando uso casi este mismo codigo pero sin utilizar ningun tipo de framework si imprime pero dentro de angular/ionic no lo hace, no se que suceda a pesar de que las variables las inicializo directamente cuando las declaro o en el constructor la impresion siempre me devuelve exactamente el mismo valor `undefined`

Comment: parece que esta dando un error por el signo de dolar. Prueba cambiando el valor a **this.graphDefinition='graph TD';**  y revisa si funciona bien.

Comment: @DavElsanto en general ya vi y no me deja imprimir nada en absoluto. Y aunque funcionara necesito el template literal con el signo de dolar para imprimir todo lo que yo quiero. Vuelvo a mencionar con o sin signos de dolar o con o sin signos para template literal no funciona nada.

Comment: Creo que el verdadero problema es que intentas seguir usando js(vanilla) en lugar de usar Angular y TypeScript. Por ejemplo añades eventos **click** usando js cuando los puedes renderizar directo en la vista y que angular se haga cargo de eso. Agrega por favor la vista del **.ts** que agregaste. Recuerda ademas que al usar angular(archivos **.ts**) este va a ser compilado a **.js** es por eso preferible usar solo Angular con TypeScript. O en su defecto usar Angular con Javascript vanilla(que es muy complejo pero se puede)

Comment: @DavElsanto la razon por la que no agrego las funciones directo en la vista es que se tratan de elementos svg que aparecen dinamicamente en la pantalla despues de que leen el `this.graphDefinition` por lo que no se puede agregar nada de eso directamente con angular, es por eso que lo paso por la parte de typescript y aunque paresca raro todo ese codigo que esta ahi todo es typescript pero estoy tambien implementando una libreria de diagramas llamada `mermaid` que me lee por completo ese string que esta en el codigo y que me permite mostrar dicho diagrama.

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo de la vista?

Comment: @DavElsanto listo, ya esta agregado

Comment: acabo de revisar https://mermaid-js.github.io y entiendo lo que necesitas. Sin embargo el error que estas obteniendo es por la concatenacion de tus variables.

Comment: @DavElsanto entonces como hago para resolver el error porque a pesar de que ya eh hecho un ejemplo con las variables sin ningun tipo de concatenacion y tratando de imprimir un string simple aun asi me sigue mandando el undefined.

Comment: Si te está generando los diagramas?

Comment: @DavElsanto si y eso es lo que se me hace raro. No me imprime el string pero si me lanza el diagrama.

Comment: Entonces la respuesta es simple, debes buscar la forma de construir bien el string, queria darte un ejemplo pero lamentablemente agregaron unas reglas en el firewall y no me deja crear proyectos de ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bueno, respondiendo a lo que te pasa, he replicado el problema, lo que te pasa es que la forma como agregas tus metodos en los **addEventListener** no es la apropiada, debes realizarlo con la función de flecha:*

*Puedes apoyarte en las siguientes páginas para entender mejor el manejo de las funciones de flecha:*

**[https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1339-fundamentos-javascript/2625-explicacion-sobre-funciones-flecha-*arrow-functions*/](https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1339-fundamentos-javascript/2625-explicacion-sobre-funciones-flecha-_arrow-functions_/)**

**http://www.etnassoft.com/2016/06/22/las-funciones-flecha-en-javascript-parte-1/**

*Lo que tienes:*

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.mermaidStart();
  for (let i = 0; i < this.agregar.length; i++) {
    this.agregar[i].addEventListener("click", this.addElement, false);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < this.respuesta.length; i++) {
    this.respuesta[i].addEventListener("click", this.addRespuesta, false);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < this.cotizacion.length; i++) {
    this.cotizacion[i].addEventListener("click", this.addCotizacion, false);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < this.pregunta.length; i++) {
    this.pregunta[i].addEventListener("click", this.addCotizacion, false);
  }
}
```

*Como lo debes ajustar:*

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.mermaidStart();
  for (let i = 0; i < this.agregar.length; i++) {
    this.agregar[i].addEventListener("click", () => this.addElement(), false);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < this.respuesta.length; i++) {
    this.respuesta[i].addEventListener("click", () => this.addRespuesta(), false);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < this.cotizacion.length; i++) {
    this.cotizacion[i].addEventListener("click", () => this.addCotizacion(), false);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < this.pregunta.length; i++) {
    this.pregunta[i].addEventListener("click", () => this.addCotizacion(), false);
  }
}
```

*El último parametro de tu addEventListener es opcional. pruebalo y nos cuentas como te va.
Espero haber sido de ayuda.*

Comment: Solo una cosa, me podrias decir los detalles de por que es necesario colocar las funciones de flecha, habia encontrado el problema hace un momento pero no entiendo la diferencia entre un metodo y otro.

Comment: Te modificare mi respuesta y te adjuntaré unos links donde puedas ver mejor varias cosas, con exactitud no podría explicartelo, pero pueden ayudarte mucho los links